# como configuro una DNS?

Tags: dns

hice la configuracion de los registros de DNS con cloudeflare pero sigue pendiente la actualizacion del servidor de nombres, ya pasaron mas de 24hs.

Comment: Hola, ya hablaste con el servicio técnico de Cloudflare?? Aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender como funciona Stackoverflow y el apartado [ask] para tener las pautas necesarias para que tu pregunta capte la atención y sea respondida. También proporciona un [Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de lo que has hecho o errores que tienes y fundamentalmente parte del código que has utilizado (en texto, no imagen).

Comment: es una cuenta gratuita, no tiene servicio tecnico, solo puedo ver otras consutlas realizadas. Voy a aprovechar el rechorrido de bienvenida. Gracias.

Comment: Que raro, yo había editado mi comment anterior diciéndote que si no podías pagar que probaras con [Lets Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/es/). Pero vuelvo y te lo dejo en este comment.